# Identify year of sheetrock

Tags: drywall

[image]Can someone assist with confirming my suspicion that this was manufactured in 95? I am doing a remodel on a 50s home.

Comment: Date/time of production (down to the second, often) is ink-jet dot-printed on the back of the sheet. I doubt that's a date code, though it's also pretty clearly not from the 1950's

Comment: Why would the date matter?  Sheetrock/drywall if damaged gets ripped out and replaced.  If not damaged gets painted.  Only reason for date is concern about asbestos/lead paint, but you need a test is be sure anyway.

Comment: how do you know it's not from 2035? Looks pretty clean...

Comment: @dandavis  Of things to have from 2035, sheetrock is probably very far down the list.  Lotto numbers, sports almanac I want, sheetrock not so much.

Comment: @crip659 - sure, but based on everything else we know about this universe, sheetrock is the best we’re going to get…

Comment: A identifier like that is usually the label's itself. Could be completely arbitrarily; could mean it's 95 and onwards. It's screaming 1999 to me, but that just coincides with having handled several hundred sheets a day during the boom.

Comment: If there's sheetrock, the home has already been remodeled. :)

Comment: If you are doing a remodel, why do you need to know the year of the sheetrock that the particular end tape came from?

Answer (score 2):

The only way you'll find out from the end-tape alone is to send that image to USG and ask.  Like @Ecnerwal said in the comments, the production code is going to be printed on the back of the sheet.

Based on the logo and end-tape design, I would say it's from the 80s or 90s.  Panels made before the 80s rarely used two colors of ink on their end-tape, and panels that are pre-1972 rarely have end-tapes with a white background.

Comment: Red letters on a white background; late 90s rush at the latest, when they were coming still hot from the factory, +1. "The board date code is printed on the back of all gypsum board. This code lists the month, day, year, plant, and time that the board was manufactured. i. For example, a board manufactured on October 15, 2005 in Seattle at 10:15, would have a board date code of 10 15 05 S 10:15."